# Populating form fields using TAL/Chameleon

Tags: python, templates, chameleon, template-tal

I'm using Chameleon in Python to render my templates.

Let's say I want to populate a form field using POST/GET data:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${request.params['foo']}" />
```

The problem with that is if request.params has no key "foo", I get an error.  What's the simplest way to have value="" be empty if the key doesn't exist, rather than throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.params` is a dict (or dict-like) object, so you can just use `.get()` with a default value:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" value="${request.params.get('foo', '')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was extending request with a simple function:

```
def get_param(self, name):
    if name in self.params:
        return self.params[name]
    return None
```